# How to order listitem based on custom sequence?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am getting some xml data as list in the below **uniqueCD**  variable. After getting all the data I want it to change the order of the data based on my own requirement, and the order should be like:

1. Amazon
2. Soap.com
3. Drugstore.com
4. Walmart
5. Target

```
var uniqueCD = (from n in xdoc.Descendants("retailer")
                  .Where(x => x.Element("instock").Value.Contains("true"))
                  select n).Distinct(new XElementComparer()).ToList();
```

**Xml data geting from list:**

```
<retailers>
  <retailer>
    <name>&lt;![CDATA[ Walmart ]]&gt;</name>
    <instock>&lt;![CDATA[ true ]]&gt;</instock>
  </retailer>
  <retailer>
    <name>&lt;![CDATA[ Soap.com ]]&gt;</name>
    <instock>&lt;![CDATA[ true ]]&gt;</instock>
  </retailer>
  <retailer>
    <name>&lt;![CDATA[ Restockit ]]&gt;</name>
    <instock>&lt;![CDATA[ true ]]&gt;</instock>
  </retailer>
  <retailer>
    <name>&lt;![CDATA[ Drugstore.com ]]&gt;</name>
    <instock>&lt;![CDATA[ true ]]&gt;</instock>
  </retailer>
  <retailer>
    <name>&lt;![CDATA[ Walgreens.com ]]&gt;</name>
    <instock>&lt;![CDATA[ true ]]&gt;</instock>
  </retailer>
  <retailer>
    <name>&lt;![CDATA[ Amazon ]]&gt;</name>
    <instock>&lt;![CDATA[ true ]]&gt;</instock>
  </retailer>
  <retailer>
    <name>&lt;![CDATA[ Target ]]&gt;</name>
    <instock>&lt;![CDATA[ true ]]&gt;</instock>
  </retailer>
</retailers>
```

Comment: That "order" looks totally arbitrary... How / Where have you defined this sequence?

Comment: Are you in control of the XML? Can you associate some sort of metadata with each retailer, that you can use for sort order? For example (given that you're in control of the XML source) you could add a `<sortOrder>` tag in the XML, and use LINQ's `.By()` to sort the list.

Comment: actly m reading multiple xml nd forming this as a seprate xml.

Comment: no @Thomas i cant add any <sortorder> in my xml

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any business logic where you could dervive an algorithm (ie alphabetical), then I would recommend a custom extension method to do your sorting.  You'll have to hard code it, so it wont be *fancy* or *performant* , but it'll work:

```
public static IEnumerable<XElement> CustomSort(this IList<XElement> elms)
{
    yield return elms.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Amazon");
    yield return elms.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Soap.com");

    //etc

}
```

And then call this method from your linq statement:

```
       (from n in xdoc.Descendants("retailer")
              .Where(x => x.Element("instock").Value.Contains("true"))
              select n)
       .Distinct(new XElementComparer()).ToList()
       .CustomSort().ToList();
```

Comment: can you plz tll me what willvl happen if "soap.com" will not be thr in my existing data..will it ignore it or throw error.

Comment: In this case it would return `null` for any missing values

Answer (score 1):

You can try to specify mapping of retailer name to rank preference in a suitable data structure, for example `Dictionary<string, int>` :

```
private Dictionary<string, int> retailerRank = new Dictionary<string, int>()
                                                 {
                                                     {"Amazon", 1},
                                                     {"Soap.com", 2},
                                                     ......
                                                     ......
                                                 };
```

Then create a function to get retailer rank based on dictionary mapping, and use the function for `OrderBy` operation in your LINQ :

```
private int getRetailerRank(string retailer)
{
    var match = retailerRank.FirstOrDefault(o => retailer.Contains(o.Key));
    return match.Value == 0 ? int.MaxValue : match.Value;
}
....
var uniqueCD = (from n in xdoc.Descendants("retailer")
                              .Where(x => x.Element("instock").Value.Contains("true"))
                select n
                ).Distinct(new XElementComparer())
                 .OrderBy(o => getRetailerRank(o.Element("name").Value))
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an array with the custom sort values and then use the array index for the ordering value.

```
var ordering = new [] {"Amazon", "Soap.com"};
var orderedCollection = coll.OrderBy(item => Array.IndexOf(ordering, item.SomeProperty));
```